# elasticsearch unique values aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I want to get the unique values from elasticsearch in the field named "name",
i do not know how can i put the condition where the values have to be unique.

The purpose of this work is the fetch all the unique names from the elasticsearch database.

```
So basically what i need is a aggregation query that fetch the unique values
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue, thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `terms` aggregation on a field which is `not_analyzed`.

However, this is by default limited to the 10 most popular terms. You can change this by updating the `size` parameter of the `terms` aggregation. Setting it to `0` will allow you to have up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` different terms (see the documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html?q=terms%20agg#_size)).

Here is an example mapping:

```
POST terms
{
  "mappings":{
    "test":{
      "properties":{
        "title":{
          "type":"string",
          "index":"not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Adding some documents :

```
POST terms/test
{
  "title":"Foundation"
}


POST terms/test
{
  "title":"Foundation & Empire"
}
```

Finally, the request :

```
POST terms/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "By Title": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title",
        "size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

will give you what you need :

```
"aggregations": {
      "By Title": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "Foundation",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "Foundation & Empire",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

Be aware that if you have a large number of terms, this request will be **very expensive** to execute.